# kubectl how to list all contexts

Tags: kubectl

How do I view all the contexts I have set up with kubectl?

It doesn't appear there's a resource known to kubectl as 'contexts'

```
$ kubectl get contexts
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "contexts"
```

Comment: I would recommend you to add a favorite in your browser to the official Cheat sheet Doc: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-context-and-configuration You will find even more good command to use.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

You can view all contexts via the config command

```
$ kubectl config get-contexts
```

Comment: and use `kubectl config use-context my-context-name` to switch contexts

Answer (score 9):

For the `kubectl` command, use this command to list all the contexts:

```
kubectl config get-contexts
```

You can view the default config file that locates at `~/.kube/config`, it contains more info like `clusters`, `users`, ...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to you answer, you can use [kubectx](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx) tool to easily switch between clusters and namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

If you are a ZSH user and have [ohmyzsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh) and kubectl [plugin](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/kubectl) enabled, then issue

`kcgc` command!